# Is it possible to change the socket timout for a single select?

Tags: mongodb, grails

Our project uses mongodb to store its documents.  We have it configured in our DataSource.groovy file with a socketTimeout of 60000.  Most of our queries do not get any where near that threshold, but I assume we have it just in case something goes wrong.

Anyway, now I am working on a query that is known to be a long running query.  It is pretty much guarenteed to be doing a tablespace scan, which we acknowledge and are ok with for now.  The problem is the amount of data we currently have is causing it to exceed the socket timeout on random cases.  Add to the issue that we are expecting the amount of data to grow considerably larger in the future.

So my question is, is it possible to increase/remove the socket timeout for a single mongodb select?  I've found the following:

```
grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('mongoDatastore').mongo.mongoOptions.socketTimeout = 0
```

That appears to work, but that also is changing the socket timeout for everything application wide I assume, which we do not want.  Help!

Update: After a lot of trial and error, I found a way to open another mongo connection that reuses the configuration, but leaves off the socketTimeout and appears to work.

```
class MongoService {
    def grailsApplication

    def openMongoClientWithoutSocketTimeout() {
        def datastore = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('mongoDatastore')
        def config = grailsApplication.config.grails.mongo
        def credentials = MongoCredential.createCredential(config.username, config.databaseName, config.password.toCharArray())
        def options = MongoClientOptions.builder()
            .autoConnectRetry(config.options.autoConnectRetry)
            .connectTimeout(config.options.connectTimeout)
            .build()

        new MongoClient(datastore.mongo.getAllAddress(), [credentials, credentials], options)
    }

    def selectCollection(mongoClient, collection) {
        def mongoConfig = grailsApplication.config.grails.mongo
        mongoClient.getDB(mongoConfig.databaseName).getCollection(collection)
    }
}
```

Not sure if this is the simplest solution though...

Answer (score 0):

What version of mongo do you use? Possible [maxTimeMS](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/method/cursor.maxTimeMS/?_ga=1.189684386.869894448.1432318709#cursor.maxTimeMS) can help you?
From document page :

```
    db.collection.find({description: /August [0-9]+, 1969/}).maxTimeMS(50)
```

Comment: 2.13  I don't see a maxTimeMS option.  Only a maxTime() option which we tried and does not override the socketTimeout option in the config.

Comment: it's available since 2.6, seems you have no more options.